# How to use the CommandManager and still be able to trigger the ICommand.CanExecuteChanged event manually i.e. explicitely?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, c#-5.0, commandbinding

I have written myself a SingleExecutionCommand (I’m not sure about that name yet. Feel free to suggest an other, but that’s not my question), which doesn’t allow a button to be pressed again before the first execution is finished. Well, at least that’s the plan.
I want to use the `CommandManager` to handle my CanExecuteChanged-Event, but I also need to trigger this event on my own whenever I change my `ExecutionIsRunning`-Flag.

This is the Code of my Command:

```
public class SingleExecutionCommand<T> : DelegateCommand<T>
{

    protected readonly Func<T, Task> AwaitableExecuteDelegate;

    public bool ExecutionIsRunning { get; protected set; }

    public SingleExecutionCommand(Func<T, Task> awaitableExecute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null) :
        base(null, canExecute)
    {
        AwaitableExecuteDelegate = awaitableExecute;
    }

    public SingleExecutionCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
        : base(execute, canExecute)
    {
        AwaitableExecuteDelegate = null;
    }        

    public async override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null && !(parameter is T)) throw new ArgumentException("Command Parameter has the wrong type.");

        if (AwaitableExecuteDelegate == null)
        {
            ExecutionIsRunning = true;
            base.Execute(parameter);
            ExecutionIsRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ExecutionIsRunning = true;
            await AwaitableExecuteDelegate((T)parameter);
            ExecutionIsRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return (!ExecutionIsRunning) && base.CanExecute(parameter);
    }
}
```

If tried to do this in my `DelegateCommand<T>`-Class:

```
protected void FireCanExcuteChangedEvent()
{
    if (CanExecuteChanged == null) return;

    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

but that doesn’t work, because that event is a rerouted event (to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`) and not a real event. So, how can I use both, the `CommandManager` and my own event?

**Edit:**
The `CanExecuteChanged`-event looks like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the handlers are assigned/delegated to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event, I suggest to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.
This will raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event to signal that the conditions regarding the validity of a command have changed. All listeners will now reevaluate if they can execute the command by responding with a `CanExecute()` call. If the result is `false` the command source usually will be disabled.

Your fixed `FireCanExcuteChangedEvent()` would look as followed:

```cs
protected virtual void FireCanExcuteChangedEvent()
{
  CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Note that will raise the `CanExecuteCHanged` event globally i.e. on every `ICommand` instance (where the `CanExecuteCHanged` event invocation is delegated to the `CommandManager`). If performance is a concern, consider to raise CanExecuteChanged explicitly for each instance (see example below).

An improved implementation would introduce a dedicated internal event delegate. This delegate will accumulate the event handlers of the `CanExecuteChanegd` subscribers in addition to delegating them to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event.
This way you have both options:

- notify event observers based on the global `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event
- notify based on the local i.e. instance event version of `CanExecuteChanged` (independent of `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`).

The following example also allows to disable the `CommandManager` based invocation of the `CanExecuteChanged` event.
This way the command *must* be explicitly invalidated by calling the public `InvalidateCommand()` method:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{   
  // Optional feature:
  // Allow to bypass the CommandManager completely 
  // to use explicit command invalidation only (via the public InvalidateCommand method).
  // Set from constructor.
  public bool IsCommandManagerInvalidateRequeryEnabled { get; }

  // Store CanExecuteChanged event handlers 
  // to invoke them independent from the CommandManager
  private EventHandler canExecuteChangedDelegate;

  public RelayCommand(bool isCommandManagerInvalidateRequeryEnabled)
  {
    this.IsCommandManagerInvalidateRequeryEnabled = isCommandManagerInvalidateRequeryEnabled ;
  }

  // Invalidate this command explicitly.
  // Raises the ICommand.CanExecuteChanged event of this instance.
  public void InvalidateCommand() => OnCanExecuteChanged();

  /// Raises the ICommand.CanExecuteChanged event.
  protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged() 
    => this.canExecuteChangedDelegate?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

  // Explicit event implementation
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
      if (this.IsCommandManagerInvalidateRequeryEnabled)
      {
        // Delegate the CanExecuteChanged event invocation to the CommandManager
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
      }

      // Accumulate handlers on a local delegate 
      // to allow raising the CanExecuteChanged event independent of the CommandManager
      this.canExecuteChangedDelegate += value;
    }
    remove
    {
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
      this.canExecuteChangedDelegate -= value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I feel a little bit stupid… I look into the `CommandManager` but I somehow managed to miss this method. Thanks a lot.